# d3 treemap graphic don't recognize enter() and exit() data correctly

Tags: d3.js, treemap

I'm trying to create dynamic treemap graphic with lovely d3.js library. 
Here are sample of my code

```
element = d3.select(element[0]);
var margin = 10,
  width = parseInt(element.style('width')) - margin * 2,
  height = parseInt(element.style('height')) - margin * 2;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var canvas = d3.select('.treemap').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(-.5,-.5)')
  .style('margin', margin);

var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
  .size([width, height])
  .value(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .sticky(false);

function redraw(data) {
  d3.selectAll('.cell').remove();
  var treemapData = {};
  treemapData.children = data.map(function(d) {
      return {
        name: d.name,
        value: d.value
      };
  });

  var leaves = treemap(treemapData);

  var cells = canvas.selectAll("g")
    .data(leaves);

  var cellsEnter = cells.enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'cell')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.dx; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.dy; })
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.children ? null : color(d.name); })
    .attr('stroke', "#fff")
    .style('fill-opacity', 0);

console.log(cells.exit(), cells.enter());
}
```

And here I have stucked. 
console.log() shows that whole new data are enter(), and none are exit() !

Input data presents like

```
[{value: 590, name:"A1"}, {...}, ...]
```

without root object field, so that's why I remapped data in treemapData object.

Тhanks that you at least spent your time for reading this post so far, hope you have any suggestions.

UDP. you can check working version of my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/qtbfm08k/

Comment: You have `d3.selectAll('.cell').remove();` ... which means that you remove anything that could be in the exit() selection. Anyway, could you show how you call `redraw` ?

Comment: @tarulen 
I use `d3.selectAll('.cell').remove();` only because `cells.exit().remove()` doesn't work, so rectangles will stack with each new data set. I understand meaning of this row, and consider it during debugging.
I'm working on Angular app, so it's hard to show all cases of `redraw` call, but I can assure u that every time data contains different length array of objects with same fields.

Comment: Ok for that. Now you have `var cells = canvas.selectAll("g")` and then you append `rect` objects ... did you try `.selectAll("rect")` instead (or better, `.selectAll(".cell")` ) ?

Comment: @tarulen Thanks for hint, you point me on some thinks I don't understand.  When I am changing `var cells = canvas.selectAll("g")` on `var cells = canvas.selectAll("rect")` or `var cells = canvas.selectAll("rect")` even on `var cells = canvas.selectAll("someTralala123")`, `cells` always returns array of `rect`, [rect, rect, rect... ], each rect is DOM element which represents rectangle of treemap graphic.

Comment: @tarulen please, check out jsfiddle link from post update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

- remove `d3.selectAll('.cell').remove();`
- use the code below

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b6meLedn/4/

```
  var cells = canvas.selectAll('.cell') //select all cells
   .data(leaves);        //map the data

  cells.exit().remove();  //remove old extra elements 
  cells.enter()
   .append('rect')        //create new rectangles as necessary
   .attr('class', 'cell')

  cells                   //take all cells (old cells that have new data+extra new cells)
   .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
   ...
```

Comment: @tarulen it was an awesome solution.In addition to that how do I add text for each cell and, customize the size of rectangles.. I want to have only squares

Comment: i figured out the text thing, I have still not found solution for square

Comment: @SunilBN short answer: you can't, you would necessarily have lots of empty space around the graph.